# List indentation not preserved

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using TinyMCE text editor on the webpage. In the editor when i create a list i get a correct nested list. But when seen on the page without editor all the indentations are lost. I would like to see a correct nested list but i just see a single level list(the numbers/bullets are preserved). Using TinyMCe 4.4. Why is  HTML not indenting nested lists ?

```
<ul>
<li data-mce-style="margin: 0px;" style="margin: 0px;">dhr</br data-mce-bogus="1">
<ol><li data-mce-style="margin: 0px;" style="margin: 0px;">sgs<br data-mce-bogus="1"></li>
</ol>
</li>
<li data-mce-style="margin: 0px;" style="margin: 0px;">afa<br data-mce-bogus="1"></li>
<li data-mce-style="margin: 0px;" style="margin: 0px;">wfa<br data-mce-bogus="1"></li>
</ul>
```